# precommit hook returns list of checked marked files in tortoiseHg

Tags: python-3.x, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

precommit hook returns list of checked marked files in tortoiseHg

So Basically i am writing a pre-commit hook which, will static analysis the code and give me HTML output of error report.

What I had done:
I am done with
Get a list MODIFIED and ADDED files and run static code analyzer on it.

get Result in the form of HTML.
Most of the work is done,
But issue is, How to get list file which are marked check in TortoiseHg, Not all the list of ADDED and MODIFIED files
[image]

So in list of files, only get 2 files in this example:
1. .classpath
2. servlet-api.jar

Basically I want to read tortoiseHg Ui in python script :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK the list of checkmarked files in Tortoise is not part of the actual Mercurial data anywhere. When you run commit in THG, at that point it uses that list to instruct HG what to do.  BUT - why do you need this list? It seems like your static analyzer is already identifying everything which has changed.

Comment: You got me  @DaveInCaz, I want to run static code analyzer on checked marked files in TortoiseHg, Thats why i want to know, is there any way to read TortoiseHg UI in python script

Comment: Are you really using THG version 2? It is up to version 4 now..

Comment: I am using latest version of THg that is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After years of years research and after reading Ayurvedic books

Just kidding...............

So finally I was able to write pre-commit hooks script, after few days after posting the question here!

Pre-requisite:

- Python above version 2 or any distribution of version 3
- SonarQube running instance
- a sonar-scanner.properties file

So the pre-commit hook is

```
import subprocess
import re
import os
import json
from tkinter import *

print(os.getcwd())
#get current working directory echo pwd 
repoPath = os.getcwd() 

#hg status -a -m gives the modified files and added files 
#git status --porcelain
cmd = "hg status -a -m"

#this is the html file name to show report errors
sonarScannedReport = 'SonarScannedReport.html'

# returns output as byte string
returned_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)

# List of Modified and Added files
fileList = returned_output.splitlines()

fileList = list(fileList)
# iterate over list and find .java files
# seperate list with "." seprator
javaFilesAbsolutePaths = []
for file in fileList:
    fileExtList = file.decode("utf-8").split(".")
    if fileExtList[1] == "java":
        fileRelativePath = re.split('A |M ', file.decode("utf-8"))
        javaFilesAbsolutePaths.append(os.path.abspath(fileRelativePath[1].replace('/', '\\')))


# Working Directory to PMD working Directory

def getOutputFileName(java_file):
    fileArr = java_file.split("\\")
    return fileArr[len(fileArr) - 1].split('.')[0]


issue_found = False

javaFiles = ""
i = 0
for javaFile in javaFilesAbsolutePaths:
    if i == 0:
        javaFiles = javaFile
    else:
        javaFiles = javaFiles + "," + javaFile
# javaFiles comma separated string and now run sonar command on it.
cmd1 = " -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true "
cmd2 = "-Dsonar.java.binaries=" + repoPath.replace('\\',
                                                   '/') + "/CatalystOne/res/WEB-INF/classes -Dsonar.issuesReport.json.enable"
cmd = "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=" + javaFiles + cmd1 + cmd2

outputJsonFile = ""
AbsPath = ""
try:
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (output2, err2) = p2.communicate()
    p2_status = p2.wait()
    output = output2.decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    for o in output:
        if "INFO: Export issues to" in o:
            AbsPath = os.getcwd() + "\\.scannerwork\\sonar-report.json"
            break

    if AbsPath == "":
        print("Problem with Sonar Scanner Connections")
        exit(1)

    with open(AbsPath, 'r') as f:
        array = json.load(f)
    issues = array['issues']

    f = open(sonarScannedReport, 'w')

    HTML_OPEN = "<html><head><title>Sonar scanner report </title></head><body align='center'>"
    TABLE_OPEN = "<table>"
    TR_OPEN = "<tr>"
    TR_CLOSE = "</tr>"
    TH_OPEN = "<th>"
    TH_CLOSE = "</th>"
    TD_OPEN = "<td>"
    TD_CLOSE = "</td>"
    TABLE_CLOSE = "</table>"
    HTML_CLOSE = "</body></html>"

    table_header = TR_OPEN + TH_OPEN + "FILE" + TH_CLOSE + TH_OPEN + "L. NO" + TH_CLOSE + TH_OPEN + "Message" + TH_CLOSE + TH_OPEN + "Severity" + TH_CLOSE + TH_OPEN + "Rule" + TH_CLOSE + TR_CLOSE

    f.write(HTML_OPEN)
    f.write(TABLE_OPEN)
    f.write(table_header)
    for issue in issues:
        fileName = issue['component'].split(':')[1]
        if 'line' in issue:
            lineNo = str(issue['line'])
        else:
            lineNo = ""

        if 'rule' in issue:
            rule = str(issue['rule'])
        else:
            rule = ""
        issue_found = True;
        tr = TR_OPEN + TD_OPEN + fileName + TD_CLOSE + \
             TD_OPEN + lineNo + TD_CLOSE + \
             TD_OPEN + issue['message'] + TD_CLOSE + \
             TD_OPEN + issue['severity'] + TD_CLOSE + \
             TD_OPEN + rule + TD_CLOSE + \
             TR_CLOSE
        f.write(tr)

    f.write(TABLE_CLOSE)
    f.write(HTML_CLOSE)
    f.close()

except ValueError:
    print(ValueError)

if issue_found:
    errorMsg = "Please open following file to problems with your code :) "
    reportFilePath = os.getcwd() + "\\" + sonarScannedReport
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Error report")
    window.geometry('550x100')
    lbl = Label(window, text=errorMsg + " \n " + reportFilePath)
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    window.mainloop()
    exit(1)
else:
    exit(0)
```

Soon I will write Github readme or can make a tutorial